# Progression bar ncurses

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm trying to do a progression bar in c++ using ncurses, but I didn’t succeed yet. All the '#' appears at the same time, there is no animation. Can some one help me please.

This my code :

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ncurses.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        initscr();

        for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        {
            mvaddch(0,n,'#');
            usleep(10000);
        }
        getch();
     endwin();
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably should add `refresh();` after `mvaddch(0,n,'#');`. Otherwise the screen appears all at once at the end of the loop in your example..