# how to print on the same line inside function, avoid flush

Tags: c++, printing, stdout, cout, carriage-return

I want to display a progress bar however putting the printing code inside a separate function seems to invoke an std::flush as each time the progress bar is printing in a new line. This did not happen when the code was used inline
The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

void load(int curr, int total) {
    std::cout << "\n[";
    int pos = 50 * curr/total;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        if (i < pos) std::cout << "=";
        else if (i == pos) std::cout << ">";
        else std::cout << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "]" << int(float(curr)/(float)total * 100.0) << " %\r";
    std::cout.flush();
}

int main(){
    
    for( int i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ){
        load(i,5);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What it does:

```
[>                                                 ]0 %
[==========>                                       ]20 %
[====================>                             ]40 %
[==============================>                   ]60 %
[========================================>         ]80 %
[==================================================]100 %
```

What it's supposed to do: print all on the same line

Comment: remove the '\r' use ansi codes to return to beginning of the line.

Comment: If you don't flush, the output won't be displayed until the internal buffer is full.

Comment: `<unistd.h>` is Unix-only.

Comment: @Jeffrey what do you mean by ansi codes exactly? could you please provide a source? google seems to give irrelevant things only with ascii

Comment: Proper way is not to use standard output for this case. Note standard output is stream of data and doesn't have to be associated with console. I would check if `ncurses` library can do it.

Comment: @Eljay so functions _have_ to flush the stdout?

Comment: @Casey i am on an ubuntu machine

Comment: @MarekR thank you Marek, i will look into it

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/q/23006822/1387438

Comment: can you show the output you got when the code was not in a function? I don't understand how it could do what you want

Comment: The fundamental issue is that some terminals or consoles will interpret "\r" and carriage return **and** linefeed.  You should search the internet for "c++ cursor positioning library".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line in your function outputs `\n`, which is what makes it print on a new line every iteration.

Fix:

```
#include <iostream>

void load(int curr, int total) {
    std::cout << '[';

    int pos = 50 * curr/total;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        if (i < pos) std::cout << '=';
        else if (i == pos) std::cout << '>';
        else std::cout << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << ']' << int(float(curr)/(float)total * 100.0) << " %\r" << std::flush;
}

int main(){

    for( int i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ){
        load(i, 5);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```